# ASP.NET MVC 3 url routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I'm having some trouble grasping MVC routing. I've read and read and it still doesn't make much sense. I'm trying to map the route "Teams/Summary?teamID=30" so that it displays "Teams/30" in the browser. This is what I have at the moment but I can't understand why it doesn't work:

```
//Teams routes
routes.MapRoute(
        "TeamsSummary",
        "Teams/{teamID}",
        new { controller = "Teams", action = "Index", teamID = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

By "doesn't work", I mean that the webpage loads but it still displays "Teams?teamID=30" in the browser address bar.

Could someone help me to understand what I need to do to perform such a simple mapping? By the way, I don't have any other routes set up that I think would interfere and it is listed before the default route in my Global.asax.cs file.

If you have some good articles and tutorials for this subject, that would be helpful as well. Thanks.

**Edit:**
The route works fine if I type the URL in manually. The problem now occurs when I use a form to post back to the controller:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(TeamsViewModel model)
    {
        if (model.teamID != null)
            model.TeamSummary = new TeamSummaryViewModel(model.teamID);

        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Teams";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Teams",FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("teamID", new SelectList(Model.Teams,"teamID","Name"))    
    <input type="submit" value="Filter"/>
}
@if (Model.TeamSummary != null)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_TeamSummary", Model.TeamSummary);
}
```

**Edit2:**
Changed the original action to the Index on the TeamsController rather than Summary as it was previously.

Comment: Can you show the `Html.ActionLink` code that you're using to generate the link? Does the route work if you manually type in one that should work?

Comment: Hi, thanks. The route works fine when I type it into the browser manually. Edited my question to include the controller and view.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, the route doesn't appear to have anything obviously wrong with it.

Maybe you need to specify a default for the `TeamID`? Wouldn't hurt to add a restriction to the `TeamID` parameter as to better define the route and allow other routes under `Teams`

E.g.

```
context.MapRoute(
        "TeamsSummary",
        "Teams/{teamID}",
        new { controller = "Teams", action = "Summary", teamID = "" },
        new { teamID = @"\d+" }
    );
```

**UPDATE**

Your code

```
Html.BeginForm("Index","Teams",FormMethod.Get)
```

Is going to create a form which sends information back to the browser as a GET rather than a POST. Which basically means that all the input values will be attached as querystring values... this is done client side and has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC Routing.

Maybe checkout the W3 Schools article on form action if you are unfamiliar - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that there's another route defined before the TeamsSummary route that is matching, you need to change the order of the routes or add constraints to make sure you match the one you want. Routing can be tricky, if you want to learn more I recommend reading [this post](http://maxtoroq.blogspot.com/2012/04/putting-aspnet-routing-to-test.html).

Answer (score 1):

You routing works perfectly well:

```
Global.asax
```

---

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "TeamsSummary",
                "Teams/{teamID}",
                new { controller = "Teams", action = "Summary" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Link created in html View:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Summary", "Summary", "Teams", new {teamID = 11 },null)%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check proper route name, must match same as specified in Global.asax file while creating an ActionLink.

Answer (score 0):

You can take away the traditional routing if you want, 
as suggested by this fellow [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/774807/Attribute-Routing-in-ASP-NET-MVC-WebAPI)

most likely if you follow that guide this will is where you could came up :

```
[Route("Teams/{teamID}")]
```

public ActionResult Index(TeamsViewModel model)
    {
        if (model.teamID != null)
            model.TeamSummary = new TeamSummaryViewModel(model.teamID);

```
    return View(model);
}
```